# Profile picture

Tags: support

I joined Stack Overflow a few days back. In my profile, I am not able to see my profile picture. Is the profile picture given by Stack Overflow or I have a problem with my uploaded profile picture?

Comment: I see it too - your avatar is generating an HTTP 400 error.  Dunno how you uploaded it but I'm not convinced that they should be coming from googleusercontent.

Comment: If you have provided a "link from the web", maybe try uploading it instead.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Stack Overflow image uploading is powered by Imgur.

Try [directly uploading the image to Imgur](https://imgur.com/upload), and then pasting the link for your profile image.

Comment: I just drag'n'drop the image into the pop-up that comes when I want to change my profile picture and chose to [Upload a new picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mpb7.png). Then the url of the image becomes `i.stack.imgur.com/XXXX.png`